# Connecting to Kerberized solr on cloudera from karaf

Tags: authentication, solr, kerberos, karaf

I'm trying to connect to Solr (non cloud) which has Kerberos enabled from my SolrJ application running in Karaf container.
 With Kerberos disabled, I'm able to connect fine.
 With Kerberos enabled, I'm able to connect outside of Karaf by running a simple SolrClient class.
 But its not working from within karaf.

Code:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "<path to jaas.conf file>");
String urlString = "http://<IP>:8983/solr/test";
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);
QueryResponse sresponse = server.query( squery );
```

**Exception in Karaf on trying to query:**
2016-12-15 15:02:17,969 | WARN  | l Console Thread | RequestTargetAuthentication      | ?                                   ? | 271 - wrap_mvn_org.apache.httpcomponents_httpclient_4.3.2 - 0.0.0 | NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials p
rovided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Invalid option setting in ticket request. (101)))
2016-12-15 15:03:10,731 | ERROR | l Console Thread | Error:org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSol
rException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 - Error report

## HTTP Status 401 - Authentication required

**type** Status report

**message** Authentication required

**description** This request requires HTTP authentication.

#### Apache Tomcat/6.0.44